# how to determine if AxAcroPDF reader has loaded or is busy

Tags: axacropdf

Please guys help me with this problem. 
I have an application writen in VB.net that uses AxAcroPDF. I need to show a "busy" message when the control is still loading. Please how to i get the status of the control at any time?

Comment: Thanks Hawk. I have trid the available properties but i dont seem to find any that reflects status. If you can help, Please assist.